# jQuery change date automatically without refresh the page using setInterval

Tags: javascript

I need the date always auto refresh on my js function.

```
function jadwal_sholat()
{
    geo = [1.03000000, 103.92000000, 3.07];
    timezone = +7;

    prayTimes.tune( {imsak: 2, subuh: 2, dhuhur: 2, ashar: 2, maghrib: 2, isya: 2} );

    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, geo, timezone);
    var list = ["Subuh", "Dhuhur", "Ashar", "Maghrib", "Isya"];
    var thisday=date.getDay();
    var thismonth=date.getMonth();
    var thisdate=date.getDate();
    var thisyear=date.getFullYear();
    var months = new Array("Januari", "Pebruari", "Maret", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Agustus", "September", "Oktober", "Nopember", "Desember");
    var name_of_days = new Array("Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jum"+"'"+"at", "Sabtu");
    var day_name = name_of_days[thisday];
    var monthname = months[thismonth];
    var tanggal = day_name+", "+thisdate+" "+monthname+" "+thisyear;

    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+tanggal+'</th></tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<tr><td style="width:50%";>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
        html += '<td align="center">'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+'</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '<tr><th colspan="2" style="margin:0;padding:0;font-weight:normal;text-align:left;"><ul style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:5px 3px;"><li>Imsak&nbsp;:&nbsp;'+times.imsak+'&nbsp;'+'</li><li>Subuh&nbsp;: 20&deg; ,&nbsp;Isya&nbsp;: 18&deg;</li><li>Waktu sudah ditambah 2 menit</center></li></ul></td></tr>';
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
}

function show() {
    jadwal_sholat();
}

window.onload=function(){show()}
```

I want the date change based on today date on refresh maybe using setInterval?

```
var date = new Date(); // today
```

I need to do that, because every change date data will different value.

Is it possible to use jQuery auto refresh maybe to set interval every 1 second?

Additional info

[image]

As you can see above image, the function will load time pray. And now I want it show automatically if We are on tomorrow date without refreshing the browser.

Means, date will change to 31 Oktober 2017 and then the following pray time will get based on current date.

Comment: `because every change date data will different value` I can't see how your data will change every second. Can you highlight which part will change every second?

Comment: I didn't get your question, what's the problem with using `setInterval(jadwal_sholat, 1000);` ?

Comment: Hi All, please refer to my updated question.

Comment: Hi, can you add the declaration to the variable `prayTimes`

Comment: Hi... here: http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set timeout and call the function `jadwal_sholat`. Below is a sample code you need to add. This will update time without refreshing the browser.

```
loadTime = function(){
    jadwal_sholat();
    setTimeout(loadTime, 1)
}
loadTime();
```

Working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkLna719/

Comment: Is it will change automatically if the time is 00.00 ? I tried to change my computer date to tomorrow, but it's not change the date

Comment: It takes the system time ... have you saved the time when you edited it? I can see that a change when i change my system time

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do the work

```
setInterval(function(){ jadwal_sholat(); }, 1000*60*24);
```